# Including a class requiring a input argument to its constructor in another class

Tags: c++, class, explicit

I have a third party libary which defines a class as follows

```
class ClassA{
    
public:
    explicit(std::string token) : _token(token);
    
    inline const std::string& getToken() const{
        return _token;
    }
    
    // Other functions
    // ...

private:
    const std::string _token;
    // other members
    // ...
};
```

I am trying to make the class a member of an another class. However, since `ClassA` requires the constructor with an input argument, is there a workaround to define another class that gets the `token` and creates an object?

```
class ClassB{
    ClassB(std::string token) : m_TOKEN(token){ setBot(); };
    
    void setBot(){
        m_classA(m_TOKEN); // I know this does not work, it is just to illustrate my question.
    };
    
private:
    std::string m_TOKEN;
    ClassA m_classA;    
}
```

Comment: Since you're using an initializer list for `m_TOKEN`, why not use it for `m_classA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your `ClassB` will not work, as `ClassA` does not have a default constructor, so you will have to initialize `m_classA` in the member initialization list of `ClassB`'s constructor.  If you want `setBot()` to reset `m_ClassA`, it will have to construct a new `ClassA` object.

```cpp
class ClassB{
    ClassB(std::string token) : m_TOKEN(token), m_classA(token) { };
    
    void setBot(){
        m_classA = ClassA(m_TOKEN);
    };
    
private:
    std::string m_TOKEN;
    ClassA m_classA;
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to initialize `m_ClassA` in the consturctor's member initialization list, then you will have to construct `m_ClassA` dynamically instead.

```cpp
class ClassB{
    ClassB(std::string token) : m_TOKEN(token) { setBot(); };
    
    void setBot(){
        m_classA = std::make_unique<ClassA>(m_TOKEN);
    };
    
private:
    std::string m_TOKEN;
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> m_classA;    
}
```